# Ionic 3 Keyboard doesn't work correctly on ion footer ONLY IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, wkwebview, ionic-native

#### Video of issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9iE4.jpg

#### Description:

When opening the keyboard all the ion footer stuff disappears. Just tapping again on the field will make it appear again. Check video.
THIS DOES NOT HAPPEN ON ANDROID. Only on iOS simulator and real device
Also, if using safari development mode and inspecting elements, any css modification via safari will make the footer look good again. It seems it's the initial drawing that gets broken.

#### What I tried:

Adding in config.xml
`<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />`
So ionic uses UIWebView instead of WKWebView. It works but app is very slow and other things don't work correctly as the app was built using WKWebView in mind.

Other thing that works is changing to old cordova ionic keyboard (deprecated) but when closing the keyboard all actions (button taps, navigation, etc) stops working on the app...

Tried forcing css/html rerender on keyboard opening, playing with field focus and changing between different plugin versions. Noone worked.

#### Code Setup:

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="chatSession && chatSession.IsComplete != 'True'" >
<ion-toolbar  color="white" style="border-top: 1px solid #4a87ee; min-height: 45px !important">
  <ion-grid no-padding>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-1 style="margin:auto">
            <ion-icon style="padding: 5px;" name="menu" class="icon-chat" (click)="openCannedMessages()"></ion-icon>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-9 style="margin:auto">
              <ion-textarea #inputRef [(ngModel)]="chatText" 
              name="chat" id="chattextarea" autocorrect="on" class="chat-area" style="padding: 0px; margin:0px" [placeholder]="this.placeholderText" ></ion-textarea>
            </ion-col>
          <ion-col col-2 style="margin:auto">
            <button ion-button outline class="btn-send" (click)="actionChat(inputRef)" style="margin: 0px; font-size: 16px;">
              <ion-label >Send</ion-label>
            </button>
          </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

#### Ionic Info:

`"@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.15.0",
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.1.3" />`

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.2
   ios-sim    : 6.1.2
   NodeJS     : v8.5.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.1.0
   OS         : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode      : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
```

Comment: hey, did you manage to find a fix for this issue ?